# How do I not refresh the list when we use navigation?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, jitpack

I use Android jitpack navigation in the project.
In the first fragment, I show the list in recyclerview.
When I click on the item, I show the second fragment.
But when I go back to the first fragment, recyclerview refreshes the old list.
How do I not refresh the list?

Answer (score 1):

You should use ViewModel to keep list through navigation. Provide the list to your fragment using LiveData and observe it in the fragment's onViewCreated() method